# Rotativa WKHTMLTOPDF rendering base 64 Image

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, wkhtmltopdf

Good day,

I'm currently experiencing Rotativa.ViewAdPdf is not rendering dynamic base64 image in ASP.net..the CSS is doing its job to process design and rotativa is rendering it. can anyone help me? please ..thanks in advance

heres my code:

CSHTML:

```
 <div Id="mainImageContainer">
                                    @if (Model.Question.MainQuestionImage != null)
                                    {
                                        <img alt="Main Image" src="@String.Format("data:{0};base64,{1}", Model.Question.MainQuestionImage.contentType, Model.Question.MainQuestionImage.content64base)" />

                                    }

                                </div>
```

Controller:

```
   public ActionResult RenderReportData(int schedId, int userId)
        {
            ScheduleExaminerModel model = new ScheduleExaminerModel();
            model = BaseMethods.GetDetails(x => x.ScheduleId == schedId && x.UserId == userId);

            ScheduleExaminerViewModel viewModel = new ScheduleExaminerViewModel();
            List<questionCorrectionViewModel> listQuestion = new List<questionCorrectionViewModel>();
            if (model != null)
            {
                viewModel.Id = model.Id;
                viewModel.User = model.User;
                viewModel.Schedule = model.Schedule;

                foreach (var item in model.Questions)
                {
                    questionCorrectionViewModel currenQuestionModel = new questionCorrectionViewModel();
                    bool iscorrect = checkAns(item);

                    currenQuestionModel.Question = item.Question;
                    currenQuestionModel.UserAnswer = item.UserAnswer;
                    currenQuestionModel.IsCorrect = iscorrect;

                    if (item.Question.QuestionType == "Essay")
                    {
                        currenQuestionModel.essayStatus = checkAnswerEssay(item);
                    }
                    listQuestion.Add(currenQuestionModel);
                }
                viewModel.CorrectedQuestion = listQuestion;



                Dictionary<string, string> cookieCollection = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                foreach (var key in Request.Cookies.AllKeys)
                {
                    cookieCollection.Add(key, Request.Cookies.Get(key).Value);
                }
                string footer = "--footer-right \"Date: [date] [time]\" " + "--footer-center \"Page: [page] of [toPage]\" --footer-line --footer-font-size \"9\" --footer-spacing 5 --footer-font-name \"calibri light\"";




                return new ViewAsPdf("UserExaminationReport", viewModel)
                {
                    Cookies = cookieCollection,
                    PageSize = Size.Letter,
                    CustomSwitches = footer
                };



            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("SystemMessage", new { message = "Record Not found" });
            }

        }
```

Model:

```
 public class FileRepositoryItem : IDataChangeTracker
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public byte[] byteContent { get; set; }
        public string contentType { get; set; }
        public decimal contentLenght { get; set; }


        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastDateUpdated { get; set; }
        public string CreateUser { get; set; }
        public string LastUpdateUser { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public string content64base
        {
            get
            {
                return Convert.ToBase64String(byteContent,0,byteContent.Length);
            }
        }
    }
```

Ive check if the CSHTML doing its job to return the base64 image array from the controller and it seem the contoller do its job heres a sample

RENDERED CSHTML:

[image]

ive tried to update rotativa and wkhtmltopdf as per the solution ive found here but no luck to get the expected output

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25062224/wkhtmltopdf-not-rendering-base64-image)

hope for someone can help me with this..

BIG THANKS Rotativa and ASP.net

REGARDS to all DEV viewing this please i need your help so badly :D

Answer (score 0):

already solve the problem i just need to uninstall the rotativa to nuget and manual delete all the files connected binaries. and reinstall updated rotativa